# Is it possible to customize the out-of-range texture value in cudaAddressModeBorder mode?

Tags: cuda, textures, gpu

When one is looking up texture values in cudaAddressModeBorder mode the values outside the texture range are set to 0. Is it possible to specify a custom value for the out-of-range texels? For example, for the application I'm working on the value 1.0 would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.

The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-memory) states:

> "If the border mode is specified instead, texture fetches with out-of-range texture coordinates return zero."